# Desperately trying to print unicode in 64 bit NASM x86 assembly with wprintf

Tags: assembly, unicode, x86, nasm

here is my code so far. I've gotten it to print a lot of question marks and it doesn't even recognize the newline in my format. I want to ultimately be able to increment the unicode value so that the function prints a set of around 50 unicode characters, but I am having a very difficult time getting it to just print one :S

```
; compile with
; nasm -felf64 Uniwc.asm && gcc Uniwc.o && ./a.out

        global main
        extern wprintf
        section .text
main:

        mov     rdi, fmt
        mov     rsi, uchar
        mov     rax, 0
        call    wprintf
        ret
uchar:
        db '/u0021'
fmt:
        db "%ls",0
```

Edit: I got similar code to work which prints a UTF-8 character by making sure to allign the stack before printing

```
; nasm -felf64 Uniwc.asm && gcc Uniwc.o && ./a.out

        global main
        extern printf
        section .text
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rdi, fmt
        mov     rsi, uchar
        mov     rax, 0
        call    printf
        pop     rbp
        ret
uchar:
        db 0x21, 0

fmt:
        db "%c", 10, 0
```

Now I am having a new problem which is that the program will not return a new character if i change the unicode in uchar for example if i change it to 0x7E (~) it still prints 0x21 (!) I assume this is an issue with the rbp register on the stack but I am uncertain to how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Your first mistake is that `/u0021` should be `\u0021`. However, that won't help you since `wprintf` expects *wide characters*, which on Linux is usually UTF-32. And NASM's `\u` syntax creates UTF-8 strings.

It seems that for now in NASM there is no other way than to just use `dd` to specify an array of codepoint values. E.g. something like:

```
uchar:
      dd '!', 0
```

The second issue is that you're using `%ls` which expects a zero-terminated character sequence, and you're passing a single character. That's why I added a zero above.

The third issue is that the format string should also be a wide character string. Try this instead:

```
fmt:
        dd '%', 'l', 's', 0
```

Comment: Just wondering, is `wprintf()` really using parameters loaded in registers, or should all of that be pushed on the stack?

Comment: It uses whatever is the calling convention of the current system. On Linux x64 it's SysV AMD64 ABI, so it uses RDI, RSI, etc.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the silly mistakes, but for what I am trying to do I can't just hardcode the value "!" I have a working nasm program that can do this. What I am specifically trying to do is print from UTF-16 code points. I will continue to fiddle around with it.

Answer (score 0):

As Igor pointed out, \u is used for UTF-8 characters. According to Nasm documentation, you can define different types of UTF strings using [these macros](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.5). You probably have to use UTF-32 on Linux and UTF-16 for Windows.