# How to print argc to the console in Netwide Assembler Windows x64?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I can't get normal result of `argc` argument. In Windows x64, it must be in `rcx` register, so I tried to print it to the console but I get result like this: `2449408`.

I expected that I get result `1`. I use Netwide Assembler, Windows 10 x64, golink. I am just tired to sit and write this code again and again.  Here my code:

```
section .data
    format: db "%d ", 10, 0
section .text
    global main
    extern printf
    main:
        push rbp
        mov rbp, rsp

        sub rsp, 32
        
        mov [rbp+16], ecx
        mov [rbp+24], rdx
        
        mov edx, ecx
        mov rcx, format
        call printf

        mov rsp, rbp
        pop rbp
        xor rax, rax
        ret
```

My commands are: `nasm -fwin64 myfile.asm` and `golink /console /entry start myfile.obj kernel32.dll shell32.dll msvcrt.dll`. I get an error but when i print this error it displays as `87` but in the debugger it displays as `57`. Here my code:

```
section .data
    integerFormat: db "%d 
section .text
    global start
    extern GetLastError
    extern CommandLineToArgvW, GetCommandLineA
    extern printf


    start:
        push rbp
        mov rbp, rsp

        sub rsp, 48

        mov dword [rbp-4], dword 0
        call GetCommandLineA

        mov rcx, rax
        mov rax, [rbp-4]
        mov rdx, rax
        call CommandLineToArgvW
        mov [rbp-12], rax
        call GetLastError
        cmp rax, 0
        jnz PrintLastError

        mov rsp, rbp
        pop rbp

        xor eax, eax
        ret
        PrintLastError:
            mov rcx, integerFormat
            mov edx, eax
            call printf
            mov rsp, rbp
            pop rbp
            mov rax, 1
            ret
```

Also I know that GetCommandLineA works fine but GetCommandLineW returns string like this: `m\0y\0f\0i\0l\0e\0` and you may know that \0 means that the string is over so I wrote GetCommandLineA. And also I know that CommandLineToArgvW returns NULL, exactly 0.

Comment: Have you used a debugger to check register values on entry to `main`?  It should be getting called with ECX=argc and RDX=argv, if you link it the same way a C compiler's `main` would.  But if it's actually the process entry point without CRT startup code, probably Windows entry-point functions get different args.  They just get one flat string of args, unlike Unix, so each program has to tokenize its own arg string into words.  So there wouldn't be an `argc` before that happens.

Comment: I wonder if `2449408` could be a pointer?  It's `0x256000` which is the start of a page, and not too high or low.  It's also looks suspiciously human-chosen.  `0x256` isn't special, but decimal `256` is...

Comment: Just because you named your entry point `main` doesn't magically tell the linker to link with the C runtime and do all the initial setup. You need to tell the linker to do that (not sure if GoLink can). See: [What is the signature of mainCRTStartup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24883460)

Comment: Sidenote: avoid `xor rax, rax`. Prefer `xor eax, eax` which has the same effect, is 1 byte shorter, and is always recognized as a zeroing idiom.

Comment: The `GetCommandLineW()` function returns a UTF-16 string (each character takes 2 bytes). `GetCommandLineA()` cannot be used directly with `CommandLineToArgvW()` (but you can use something like [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar) or [`mbsrtowcs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbsrtowcs) to convert the output).

Comment: @DarkAtom, Okay, I just change my calling of GetCommandLineW. But I still get the same error from GetLastError. This error displays as `87` in the console but as `57` in the debugger IDA.

Comment: The reason you are getting an error (which is decimal `87`, hexadecimal `0x57`, [and means invalid parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)) is because you are calling the function wrong. `rcx` should contain a pointer to the wide string (in your code it is the narrow string returned by `GetCommandLineA()`), while `rdx` should be a pointer to the memory location to store `argc`, not the value there. Use `lea rdx, [rbp-4]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved my problem. I don't get this error anymore. But, please, tell me how to print this UTF-16 format string. I don't understand how to print it but understand that UTF-16 uses 2 bytes that printf can't print to the console.

Comment: Use `wprintf()`. I'm not really sure, however, if NASM has an easy way of encoding the UTF-16 format string correctly (In C you can use `L"format goes here %d"`). As I said, dealing with UTF-16 is quite annoying. If you are absolutely sure that all the characters inside the string can be represented as ASCII, you can use [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) or [`wcsrtombs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/wcsrtombs), but I don't recommend that.

Comment: If you don't like this option, you can probably stick to `GetCommandLineA()` (which returns a valid narrow string), use `MultiByteToWideChar()` to set it up for `CommandLineToArgvW()` and finally step each `argv` element down to narrow using `WideCharToMultiByte()`.

Comment: I just looked up, NASM [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23678265) encode UTF-16 strings.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't even know how to thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the C library, so you have 2 options:

### Include all the startup boiler-plate code in your program

Link the object file (`.o` or `.obj`) with `gcc` (or some other C compiler like MSVC). It will call its own linker (such as `ld`) and magically link your program with the C Runtime Library (CRT). It's just like writing a C program, but you replace the compilation step (which turns `.c` into `.o`) with the assembling step (which turns `.asm` into `.o`).

Example:

```
nasm -f win64 my_file.asm -o my_file.o
gcc my_file.o -o my_file.exe
```

### Link to the CRT

If you insist on starting from the raw entry point of the executable, you'll have to accept the fact that you don't get any arguments as parameters, and you have to do the work yourself. Use [`GetCommandLineA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea) or [`GetCommandLineW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew) from **kernel32.dll** (and possibly [`CommandLineToArgvW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) from **shell32.dll**) to aid you. The `W` functions are generally better, but Unicode in Windows is UTF-16, so it can be a bit annoying to work with.

I would also recommend avoiding the `main` name in this case because it creates confusion. GoLink prefers the name `start` as default, while `ld` prefers `_start`.

Example:

```
nasm -f win64 my_file.asm
golink my_file.obj /console /entry main msvcrt.dll kernel32.dll
```

You can omit the `/entry main` argument if you rename the label to `start` in your code.